# Access denied to Samba share from Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, samba

Samba version: Version 4.1.17-Ubuntu

Ubuntu 15.10

When accessing a Samba share in windows, I can see the share but whenever I try and access it - entering the same username and password as the Samba user created with `sudo smbpasswd -a benjamin` (same as system user), I only get "Access is Denied". Here are my smb settings

```
[global]
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
#encrypt passwords = No
map to guest = Bad User
obey pam restrictions = Yes
passdb backend = tdbsam
pam password change = Yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
unix password sync = Yes
syslog = 0
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
dns proxy = No
usershare allow guests = Yes
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

wins support = yes

name resolve order = wins lmhosts host bcast


[TVShare]
path = /media/MEDIA2/TV
available = yes
valid users = benjamin
read only = no
browsable = yes
public = yes
writable = no
```

Where `ls -dl /media/MEDIA2/TV/` reads

```
drwxrwxr-x 40 benjamin benjamin 4096 Sep  5 16:18 /media/MEDIA2/TV/
```

Sample log:

```
[2015/12/20 12:52:02,  2] ../source3/lib/tallocmsg.c:124(register_msg_pool_usage)
  Registered MSG_REQ_POOL_USAGE
[2015/12/20 12:52:02,  2] ../source3/lib/dmallocmsg.c:78(register_dmalloc_msgs)
  Registered MSG_REQ_DMALLOC_MARK and LOG_CHANGED
[2015/12/20 12:52:02.517860,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:543(max_open_files)
  rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
[2015/12/20 12:52:02.517954,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:3582(do_section)
  Processing section "[TVShare]"
[2015/12/20 12:52:02.518169,  2] ../source3/lib/interface.c:341(add_interface)
  added interface eth0 ip=192.168.0.5 bcast=192.168.0.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
[2015/12/20 12:52:02.522658,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:136(daemon_ready)
  STATUS=daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connectionsFailed to fetch record!
```

Comment: No Samba version, no logs, nothing about other versions of Windows... And have you tried to mount the share from the server machine itself?

Comment: Added. Unable to try on other versions of windows - but thought the version may be of help

Answer (score 12):

To access the samba share, please pay attention to:

1. You had to create a system user with the same username. In this case, please issue the following command: `useradd -s /sbin/nologin benjamin`
2. If you are using a SELINUX-enabled system (eg: CentOS), try to temporarily disable it issuing `setenforce 0`

EDIT: as the problem persists, try the following:

1. maybe your Windows host is prepending your username with the wrong domain name. From the Windows machine, try to login using `localhost\benjamin` as the username
2. issue `pdbedit -L` and check if user `benjamin` is listed. If so, set a trivial password (you can change it later) using `smbpasswd benjamin`
3. if user `benjamin` is not listed, try to recreate it issuing `smbpasswd -a benjamin`
4. if it does not work, delete the passwd file (it is named `passwd.tdb`; for reference, in a CentOS 6.x system it is found under `/var/lib/samba/private/`). Then, recreate your user issuing `smbpasswd -a benjamin`
5. if it still not working, try to use the root account issuing `smbpasswd -a root` and check if you can login using the root user. Note: this is only a try. After having done with it, you **must** delete root's entry issuing `smbpasswd -x root`
6. Your last resort is to increase the verbosity of logging and see if you can find clues there. For authentication attempts, edit or add the following line on your smb.conf `log level = 2 winbind:5`, check the logs with something like `tail -f /var/log/samba/log*` and try to login.

Comment: Thank you, the user I created is the same name/pass as an existing system user. I'll edit the question with more information

Comment: I've edited my answer. Give it a try.

Comment: Tried 2-5 (it did exist in pdbedit) but had the same issue. After trying one, I get a new error in Windows: "...\TVShows is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource..."

Comment: Have you disabled SELINUX?

Comment: Thank you :) creating new user with password solved my problem :)

Comment: @shodanshok do you mind if I add to your answer, one last step regarding enabling verbose logging from https://serverfault.com/a/1070611/67528 ?

Comment: @ndemou sure, feel free to propose an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 10):

It is possible you need to add the user in question to your smb service in linux

```
sudo smbpasswd -a myuser
```

Comment: tried all kinds of configurations, but this was the answer I needed :)

Comment: I would give this a bounty if I had any to give

Answer (score 6):

On the Windows PC, Change `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LmCompatibilityLevel` to 4

Network security: LAN Manager authentication level is usually set to `Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated` by Group policies for backup compatability with older clients.

Changing `LmCompatibilityLevel` to 4 sets it to `Send NTLMv2 response only`

Comment: Does this require a reboot on the client?

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LmCompatibilityLevel does not exist on my Windows 10 Home machine.
What type should it be?

Comment: @DaveBurton: `REG_DWORD`

Comment: thank you Dave, this worked for me

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me.  Just says "access denied" even after a reboot

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Eventually solved it by erasing the partition on my external HDD and remaking the filesystem. With this config I can copy&paste onto the drive without logging in from windows:

```
[global]
server string = Media Server
workgroup = HOME
security = user
map to guest = Bad User
name resolve order = bcast host

[Film]
path = /mnt/sda/sda1/Film
force user = smbuser
force group = smbgroup
create mask = 0664
force create mode = 0664
directory mask = 0775
force directory mode = 0775
public = yes
writable = yes
write list = smbuser
```

I set up the group and user with the following commands:

```
sudo groupadd --system smbgroup
sudo useradd --system --no-create-home --group smbgroup -s /bin/false smbuser
```

My drive had been used in a different system (I re-did the same server a couple of times) so I think there were still traces of ownership that was overriding my new persmissions so therefore, only after re-partition and re-making the filesystem the new permissions worked.

Answer (score 1):

Adding 'ntlm auth = yes' to global section of smb.conf on samba server worked for me.

Source:
https://bgstack15.wordpress.com/2017/10/01/samba-and-ntlm-for-windows-clients/

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this and been banging my head against a brick wall trying to work out what was happening.

I have set up lots of samba installs before and spent hours on this. As is the case it turned out to be something stupidly simple.

Symptom - Linux host shows in Windows network, but when I click on it and enter username/password I get 'Access Denied. Linux user, Samba user and all permissions set correctly

Problem - I had uncommented the 'homes' config items but not the '[homes]' share label.

As soon as I spotted this and uncommented [homes] in smb.conf it all worked properly!

Interestingly enough nothing showed this up. You can run testparm and it says everything is fine with smb.conf

I compared my set up to other running computers and everything looked fine, I simply kept missing that commented ';[homes]' entry

Answer (score 0):

Found this with a google search, it's old but adding something that worked for me when none of these other answers did.

I added an entry to the Windows Credential Manager for the remote-host-name. Nothing else worked until I did this, and then I was able to access with \\remote-host-name.